# Дважды создается поле первичного ключа Code-First ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, codefirst

Все привет друзья.

Создаю таблицы по принципу code-first
У пользователя может быть сколько угодно автомобилей.
Класс описывающие поля

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BaseModels
{
    public class BaseModelInfo
    {
       [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }


    public class User : BaseModelInfo
    {   
        public virtual Car Cars { get; set; }

    }

    public class Car : BaseModelInfo
    {
        public int User_id { get; set; }
       

    }
}
```

Миграция

```
        namespace WebApplication6.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    
    public partial class CreateCar_User : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Users",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
            
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Cars",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        //User_id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                        User_Id = c.Int(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.User_Id)
                .Index(t => t.User_Id);
            
        }
        
        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Cars", "User_Id", "dbo.Users");
            DropIndex("dbo.Cars", new[] { "User_Id" });
            DropTable("dbo.Cars");
            DropTable("dbo.Users");
        }
    }
}
```

**Подключение**

```
 namespace WebApplication6.DataModel
{
    public class DataAcces : DbContext
    {

        public DataAcces() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
        public IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public IDbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Делаю Update -Database Ошибка

```
**Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'User_Id' in table 'Cars' is specified more than once.**
```

Comment: У вас точно в `BaseModelInfo` поле `Id`, а не `User_Id`? Проверьте ещё раз, этот ли в точности у вас код даёт такую ошибку. Да, и что такое "Миграция", почему этот код в точности повторяет код класса, описывающего поля?

Comment: Это Я немного перестарался. Миграцию поправил. Закомментировал один User_id только Я понять не могу откуда второй берется?

Comment: Я не очень понимаю описание класса `User` с виртуалами. А если его закомментить вообще попробовать, может оттуда как-то утекает?

Comment: Я реализую связь через виртуал это ссылка на множество значений

Comment: `ICollection<Car> Cars` у юзера

Comment: Пользователь и автомобиль имеют общего предка - честно говоря, бредовая схема.

Comment: Поля же одинаковые, разве есть разница какой у них предок? С точки зрения объектного представления может быть

Comment: ICollection<Car> Cars а все ровно два раза User_id

Comment: Судя по наличию закомментированного кода в миграции, колонка уже была создана, а теперь пытается создастся уже с другими параметрами. Ценные данные в БД есть? Если нет, удалите её полностью и создайте заново, с нуля. Все миграции можете удалить.

Comment: Возможно, вместо общего предка есть смысл создать общий интерфейс (со свойствами Id и Name).

Comment: Я закоментировал строчку и база создалась. База пустая, ничего там нету. Удалю базу, миграции как то по особенному удалять или просто дел?

Comment: Мне кажется базовый класс не может повлиять на поведение всей программы

Comment: Сделал разные классы даже, все ровно создает 2 раза поле User_id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        User_Id = c.Int(),

Comment: у `Cars` в коде миграции два поля `User_Id` потому что в `Car` добавлять `User_Id` не надо: EF видит что Вы добавили навигационное свойство `Cars` и на этом основании сам добавляет необходимое поле

Comment: для корректной реализации связи 1 ко многим `Cars` должен выглядеть как то так: [`public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars {get; set}`](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.7.php)

Comment: если же хочется самому определить имя внешнего ключа в `Cars` то тогда через аннотацию `ForeignKey`: `[ForeignKey("UserId")]` сделает связь с таблицей Car по ключу `UserId`(ключ должен существовать в связанной таблице)